# Map-reduce job giving ClassNotFound exception even though mapper is present when running with yarn?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a hadoop job which is working fine when I am running it without yarn in  pseudo-distributed mode, but it is giving me class not found exception when running with yarn

```
16/03/24 01:43:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458775953882_0002_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.keyword.count.ItemMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.keyword.count.ItemMapper not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 8 more
```

Here is the source-code for the [job](https://github.com/CUBigDataClass/Big-Data-Project/tree/master/MapReduceExample/src/com/hadoop/keyword/count)

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("keywords", args[2]);

Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "item count");
job.setJarByClass(ItemImpl.class);
job.setMapperClass(ItemMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(ItemReducer.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Here is the command I am running

```
hadoop jar ~/itemcount.jar /user/rohit/tweets /home/rohit/outputs/23mar-yarn13 vodka,wine,whisky
```

Edit Code, after suggestion

```
package com.hadoop.keyword.count;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ItemImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("keywords", args[2]);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "item count");
        job.setJarByClass(ItemImpl.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ItemMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ItemReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }


    public static class ItemMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context output) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {

            JSONObject tweetObject = null;

            String[] keywords = this.getKeyWords(output);

            try {
                tweetObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(value.toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (tweetObject != null) {
                String tweetText = (String) tweetObject.get("text");

                if(tweetText == null){
                    return;
                }

                tweetText = tweetText.toLowerCase();
    /*          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tweetText);

                ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    tokens.add(st.nextToken());
                }*/

                for (String keyword : keywords) {
                    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase();
                    if (tweetText.contains(keyword)) {
                        output.write(new Text(keyword), one);
                    }
                }
                output.write(new Text("count"), one);
            }

        }

        String[] getKeyWords(Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) {

            Configuration conf = (Configuration) context.getConfiguration();
            String param = conf.get("keywords");

            return param.split(",");

        }
    }

    public static class ItemReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context output)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int wordCount = 0;

            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                wordCount += value.get();
            }

            output.write(key, new IntWritable(wordCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running in full distributed mode your TaskTracker/NodeManager (the thing running your mapper) is running in a separate JVM and it sounds like your class is not making it onto that JVM's classpath.

Try using the `-libjars <csv,list,of,jars>` command line arg on job invocation.  This will have Hadoop distribute the jar to the TaskTracker JVM and load your classes from that jar.  (Note, this copies the jar out to each node in your cluster and makes it available only for that specific job.  If you have common libraries that would need to be invoked for a lot of jobs, you'd want to look into using the Hadoop distributed cache.)

You may also want to try `yarn -jar ...` when launching your job versus `hadoop -jar ...` since that's the new/preferred way to launch yarn jobs.

Comment: Your comment  about distributed cache did not solve the problem above, but helped solve another problem I was facing with my hadoop jar regarding 3rd party jar.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the content of your itemcount.jar ?( jar -tvf itemcount.jar). I faced this issue once only to find that the .class was missing from the jar.

Comment: I checked the content and the class was present. Also, when I run the jar without yard it works fine. So I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error a few days ago.

- Changing map and reduce classes to static fixed my problem.
- Make your map and reduce classes inner classes.
- Control constructors of map and reduce classes (i/o values and override statement)
- Check your jar command

**old one**

hadoop jar ~/itemcount.jar  /user/rohit/tweets    /home/rohit/outputs/23mar-yarn13 vodka,wine,whisky

**new**

hadoop jar ~/itemcount.jar com.hadoop.keyword.count.ItemImpl  /user/rohit/tweets /home/rohit/outputs/23mar-yarn13 vodka,wine,whisky

- add packageName.**mainclass** after you specified .jar file

**Try-catch**

```
try {
         tweetObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(value.toString());
         } catch (Exception e) { **// Change ParseException to Exception if you don't only expect Parse error**
          e.printStackTrace();
         return; **// return from function in case of any error**
            }
}
```

**extends Configured and implement Tool**

```
public class ItemImpl extends Configured implements Tool{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    int res =ToolRunner.run(new ItemImpl(), args);
    System.exit(res);
        }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        Job job=Job.getInstance(getConf(),"ItemImpl ");
        job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

        job.setJarByClass(ItemImpl.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ItemMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ItemReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);//probably not essential but make it certain and clear
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); //probably not essential but make it certain and clear
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
 add public static map
 add public static reduce
 I'm not an expert about this topic but This  implementation is from one of my working projects. Try this if doesn't work for you I would suggest you check the libraries you added to your project.
```

Probably first step will solve it but
If these steps doesn't work , share the code with us.

Comment: Actually I tried the first step even before your suggestion. But got the same error, the only difference was class not found ItemImpl.ItemMapper.

Comment: @Dude can you explain what are vodka,wine,whisky for?

Comment: These are the keywords I am passing to the map job.

Comment: Actually my jar is runnable, so I am not supposed to give the main class.